# The cook time and temperature I need is not an option on my crockpot

Tags: temperature

How do you adjust the cook time for a recipe that says cook on low for 6 hours to coordinate with a programmable crock pot that only has settings for 4-6 hours on High and 8-10 hours on low?

Answer (score 4):

**Go for 8 hours on Low.**

2 more hours on low shouldn't hurt anything too much, for *many* slow-cooking extra cook-time can actually be beneficial. More cook-time usually means a more tender finished product.

Whatcha cookin? That would help us answer this question better.

Comment: ...though just to be on the safe side, be sure to terminate the cooking if the bouquet gets to where it fills the room; for slow-cooked dishes flavor lost to the air (in the form of a bouquet) will translate to flavor spent or, that is, a less flavorful dish when served.

Answer (score 0):

**Or go for 5-7 hours on low**

Though, yes, a longer cook time on low is not likely to harm what you're cooking (and, yes, it may be helpful to know what it is that you're cooking), if you're determined to use this machine and determined to stick to the time constraints you defined, all you can really do is think of your 6 hours on low as 5-7 hours on low --in which case you first would run your machine on its 8-10 hour setting for three hours with nothing but water (for example) in the crock and then swap out the water for your ingredients (in which event hopefully you'd find an alternate use for wasted that cook time).